# iot:Certificate.Subject.SerialNumber used to restrict shadow access

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, iot, shadow, policy

I am having difficulty using **${iot:Certificate.Subject.SerialNumber}** in a policy to restrict shadow access to the device using the specified certificate.

I have a certificate that has been issued by aws-iot with serialnumber in hex : **00 FC 63 F4 3D D8 8D 92 B1 19 5E 3C 6B D4 1B 99 1E 60 7C 86 34**

If I convert this to decimal string I get : **1440894724465102159684825527826579699971598878260**

I have attatched this certificate to a Thing with name :
**Scoot-1440894724465102159684825527826579699971598878260**

My policy is :

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:client/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:topic/$aws/things/Scoot-${iot:Certificate.Subject.SerialNumber}/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:topicfilter/$aws/things/Scoot-${iot:Certificate.Subject.SerialNumber}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

The device cannot  publish messages to the shadow topics.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. 
The certificates issued by AWS have no SerialNumber attribute in the **subject**.

They are an attribute on their own.

I should use *${iot:Certificate.SerialNumber}*
instead of   *${iot:Certificate.**Subject**.SerialNumber}*

It works now and my devices cannot access each others shadows anymore.